# Tableau Query for using DateDiff and DateTrun at same time

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am new to tableau and i need to find all row set filter on basis of given time frame and then grouping the result of same minute.I can crack this problem in Sql as following

```
select count(x)
from table t
where datediff(30, min, date)
group by datepart(min, date)
```

How to fix it in tableau ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of what you want but this will give you the number of record per minute, for the records whose date is in the last 30 minutes:

```
select datepart(MI, date) , COUNT(*) as NumberOfRecordsInMinute
from table t
where date >= dateADD(MI, -30, getdate())
group by datepart(MI, date)
order by datepart(MI, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious what your SQL is trying to do here as the standard SQL `datediff` function works like this `datediff(datepart,startdate,enddate)` and returns the difference between two dates in the units specified.

If that is what you want, then the Tableau function `datediff` does much the same job and `datediff('minute',start date,enddate)` will return the number of minutes between two datetimes and it will be grouped already because the result is discrete.

You can then count the number of records matching each minute difference.